# Show the following matrix recursion is symmetric

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, recursive-algorithms

I need to show the following matrix equation is symmetric and I'm not sure where to start:

$A_i=\sum_{j_1=1}^{i-2}2(i-j_1-1){i-2 \choose j_1-1}A_{j_1}\Big(\sum_{j_2=1}^{i-j_1-1}{i-j_1-2 \choose j_2-1}A_{j_2}A_{i-j_1-j_2} \Big)$

for $i\geq3$, where each $A_j\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric for all $j<i$. I actually have a much larger general form for this equation, but I wanted to tackle that myself once I got started. Obviously, I would proceed by induction, but the base case $i=3$ is trivial and I'm stuck on the inductive step. My first guess was to look at some notes on noncommutative symmetric polynomials. Any help/references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean that you want to show that the polynomial you get is a symmetric polynomial, or that the matrix $A_i$ is symmetric?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to show that $A_i$ is symmetric.

Comment: It looks like you only use $A_1$ in the definition of $A_3$.  If that's true, I'd recommend first generating 2 random integer entry symmetric matrices $A_1,A_2$ and then see whether $A_4$ is symmetric when you compute it.  If it's possible to get a non-symmetric answer, then you're almost guaranteed to get one when you compute $A_4$ because probably the set of $A_1$ and $A_2$ that would lead to a symmetric $A_4$ would probably be measure zero among the set of all pairs of symmetric $A_1,A_2$ (unless $A_4$ is guaranteed to be symmetric like you hope).

Comment: So, if you use the equation above, for $A_4$ you get:
$A_4 = A_1A_1A_2 + A_1A_2A_1 + A_2A_1A_1$.

And $(A_4)^T$:
$(A_4)^T=(A_1A_1A_2)^T + (A_1A_2A_1)^T + (A_2A_1A_1)^T = A_2A_1A_1 + A_1A_2A_1 + A_1A_1A_2$ since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are symmetric.

Comment: Every time I work it out with a specific $i$, it follows that $A_i$ is symmetric. I just can't PROVE this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You can prove the statement by mathematical induction. The expression for $A_i$ can be rewritten as
$$
A_i = \sum_{j+k+\ell=i}\frac{2(i-2)!}{(j-1)!(k-1)!(\ell-1)!}A_jA_kA_\ell.
$$
Split the sum into four parts, each for one of the following cases:

1. $j=k=\ell$,
2. $j,k,\ell$ are all distinct,
3. $j=\ell\neq k$,
4. $j=k$ or $\ell=k$, but not both.

In each case, prove that the partial sum constitutes a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Does one need to consider all 4 cases you listed? We know $j,k,l\neq 0$, and we are summing over all possible combinations of $j+k+l=i$. So if $a+b+c=i$ then we know we will have the terms $A_aA_bA_c$ and $A_cA_bA_a$ since we have $c+b+a=i$. The leading coefficient would work out as well in this case. Could you just make some permutation argument?